# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError (Maven project)

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel, maven-3

I try to execute my app like this `java -jar camel-blueprint-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
('camel-blueprint-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' is a maven projet), and I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/camel/main/Main
at com.mycompany.camel.blueprint.MainExample.boot(MainExample.java:19)
at com.mycompany.camel.blueprint.MainExample.main(MainExample.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.main.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 2 more
```

This is the main class:

```
package com.mycompany.camel.blueprint;

import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class MainExample {
    private Main main;   

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        MainExample example = new MainExample();
        example.boot();
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }

    public void boot() throws Exception { 
        // create a Main instance       
        main = new Main(); 
        main.enableHangupSupport();
        System.out.println("Starting Camel. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");      
        main.run(); 
    } 
}
```

I cannot found the error.
How can I fix this problem ?

This is the [pom.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6acQWnkaZmAY1VxaHFOaFU5bW8/view)

Comment: How did you create the jar? Post your pom.xml

Comment: How do you generate `camel-blueprint-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`? I think it does not include referenced libraries. It should be a fat jar (for instance as per: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/). A fat jar is different from a normal jar in the sense that referenced library are also added to the resulting jar.

Comment: i edited my question  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6acQWnkaZmAY1VxaHFOaFU5bW8/view

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifi the main class in the mainfest of the jar or specify the class you want to run:

```
java -cp camel-blueprint-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.camel.blueprint.Main
```

Comment: You cannot specify a class name is you use the `-jar` option.

Comment: thats true...with class name he should use -cp

Comment: I have the same problem.</br>this is the pom.xml: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6acQWnkaZmAY1VxaHFOaFU5bW8/view?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

What you creates is an executable JAR file that depends on other (external) JAR files.  This is not generally a good idea.  However, if you want to make it work, then when you create the JAR file, you need to arrange that it has an appropriate `ClassPath` attribute in its manifest.  The JAR file spec says this:

> *"Class-Path: The value of this attribute specifies the relative URLs of the extensions or libraries that this application or extension needs. URLs are separated by one or more spaces. The application or extension class loader uses the value of this attribute to construct its internal search path."*

But there is a catch.  The URLs are resolved relative to the location of the executable JAR file.  If the actual external JARs aren't in the expected position *as specified in the manifest* then the main JAR won't launch.

Comment: i tried this and i have the same error:  
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>src/main/java/com/mycompany/camel/blueprint</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.mycompany.camel.blueprint.MainExample</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

Comment: Are you really putting the external JAR files in the src/main/java/com/mycompany/camel/blueprint folder in ... relative to the JAR file location?  'Cos, that is what I think you told Maven to put into the Manifest!